# send app request works, but not sent to user?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to send a facebook request from the server side api (php).
I user this code:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/" . $f2 . "/apprequests?message=NewMatchpoint&data=invite_data&".$access_token."&method=post
```

and this is the response I get:

```
{"request":"355954047749908","to":["100001821928954"]}
```

I assume this means it worked, and the app request was sent, but the recipient receives nothing...
Did someone ever encounter this behavior?
Thanks...

Comment: What result do you expect? Note that app-to-user requests don't produce any notification (red number at the top of facebook page). They just add +1 to that grey number near your app bookmark link.

Comment: @Sim, wow... totally missed that from the documentation... good to know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes;  That means that the request was sent successfully. You can validate that request by querying the Graph API like so :
`"https://graph.facebook.com/$REQUEST_ID.'_'.$FBID"`.
You have to concatenate the request_id and the users Facebook id with an underscore.

Make sure (if your application is in sandbox mode) that the users you are sending the requests to are listed in the "roles" section of your applications settings...

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the late response, wasn't around a computer (for a change :). my problem is that even the gray number counter doesn't increase... simply nothing happens... ever encountered such a thing? I made sure the app is not in sandbox but other than that, no further ideas...

Comment: do you have a canvas URL in your application settings?

Comment: did you notice @Sim's comment to your question?  That with app generated requests there is no red notification "bubble".. only an increment in the bookmark counter?

Comment: thanks for pointing it, but yes, i'm aware of it... it actually started working some how after a day of leaving it along... I know what you might think, but I tested it 15 times before when it didn't work. now it just does :\